# Universal image loader add cache

Tags: android, image, caching

I know that universal image loader caching automatically when setted it up. But how can I mannuly add a bitmap or byte array to corresponds to an image URL, when it sees it next time, it load from provides bitmap. The situation is that I am sending an image to another user, the sent imageview is set by uri, but when I reload the page it will load image from server, which doesn't have a good user experience.

Thanks!